# tomcat welcome page in jsf using template

Tags: jsf, tomcat, web.xml

I have a jsf project

and my pages are all referencing a template.xhtml

currently i have the following in the web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/pages/home/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

when i try to access the root directory now it shows me some content from that page as jsf code (not rendered) but everything from within the template vanished as well. It just shows the title and 2 lines of code.

All help appreciated

Comment: Provide for further details: al least the whole web.xml, master template and template client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the url mapping for the Faces Servlet in your `web.xml` file, it's probably wrong.

A good one should be like the one at the [JSF tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: It can be rigth If the pages you refer from template is not mapped to faces servlet.

Answer (score 0):

solved it
added the following in the web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and created the following index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; faces/pages/home/index.xhtml">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```